# How to format an XML string with line breaks using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

What I'm trying is to format a string variable, which represents an XML file, with line breaks.

```
// This represents an XML file, but it's not formatted
let xmlStr = "<?xml version="1.0"?><?meta name="test"?><Foo>  <Bar>   <FooBar/>  </Bar></Foo>";
```

Now, I'm trying to come up with a function to format the string

```
xmlStr = formatXmlStr(xmlStr);
console.log(xmlStr);
```

The `console.log` above is supposed to print the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?meta name="test"?>
<Foo>
  <Bar>
   <FooBar/>
  </Bar>
</Foo>
```

I found that Javascript offers [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer), which returns an XML string based on a DOM object. However...

```
const docObj = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, 'text/xml');
const xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(docObj);

console.log(xmlString);
```

The resulting `xmlString` isn't formatted (i.e. It has no line breaks).

Is it possible to add line breaks to an XML string with Javascript?

**UPDATE**

Formatting has to be done without changing tabs (or blank spaces) in the XML string. This means, for example, [solutions posted on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238130/formatting-output-string-from-xmlserializer-serializetostring) won't be used because the resulting strings will have different lengths of tabs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting Output String from XMLSerializer().serializeToString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238130/formatting-output-string-from-xmlserializer-serializetostring)

Comment: It's possible, yes. It's just a string after all. The question is, how do you determine where to insert the line breaks. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @wuerfelfreak, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the solutions posted on the link weren't really desirable. Both of the solutions are inserting not only line breaks but also tabs. I'm in a situation where it's not allowed to change anything in the XML other than formatting. So, adding tabs isn't allowed. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no text between the `xml-tags` like in the example you presented (e.g. `<foo><bar></foo>` and not `<foo>Some Text</foo>`) one can simply do the following:

```
xmlStr.replaceAll(">",">\n")
```

which results in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?meta name="test"?>
<Foo>
  <Bar>
   <FooBar/>
  </Bar>
</Foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the label `<pre>` {Your XML string} `</pre>` in your html file.

Example:

`const response = "<item><FACTURA>91860338</FACTURA><FOLIO>0000000000000000</FOLIO> <IDOC>0000000000000000</IDOC><PEDIDO>0001661927</PEDIDO></item>"`

```
<div>
   <pre>{{response}}</pre>
</div>
```

And the result in the browser:

```
<item>
    <FACTURA>91860338</FACTURA>
    <FOLIO>0000000000000000</FOLIO>
    <IDOC>0000000000000000</IDOC>
    <PEDIDO>0001661927</PEDIDO>
</item>
```