# Format a string as if it were an XML file

Tags: javascript, angular, xml, format

I'm writing a method that is generating the body of an XML file. The method returns a string, which I then pass to
`const file = new Blob([content], {type: "text/xml"});`
as the content variable. How can I get this string to format itself as a more readable format? Specifically, I'm looking for a way to auto-indent and add newlines wherever necessary as opposed to adding them manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547725/how-to-format-an-xml-string-with-line-breaks-using-javascript

Comment: @PM77-1 that only works if there isn't any content between the tags, and my string has data between the tags

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376373/pretty-printing-xml-with-javascript then? Anything there fit your needs?